# GWT stock chart library

Tags: java, gwt, charts, stock

we are about to start a project for a java stock market charting project.
we intend to use jfreechart backed by GWT to display our stock charts.

-are there any good java stock frameworks or libraries we can use?
-is there some good GWT stock charting library that could be used in our project?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not using *jfreechart*. Rather have a look at the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). We used to use other free charting libraries (including *jfreechart*) and have moved over to the Google Charts API about 5 months ago (ported all our old code). We have never looked back. Also, it integrates brilliantly with GWT.

Comment: Great thank you for the advice. does Google charts API offers bar chart ,candle chart and all stock market chart types ? my other question is : which is best for handling feed quote query services yahoo finance api or google finance api? can you advise on these too ? thanks much

Comment: can i ask why you suggest not using jfreechart? is it b/c it is difficult to integrate jfreechart with GWT? or is it b/c jfreechart is limited in features?

Answer (score 0):

This one is a really nice HTML5 data visualization tool.  Humble Finance itself is written completely in JavaScript, utilizing the Prototype and Flotr libraries. You can use it for displaying any two 2-D data sets of real numerical data that share the axis..

This is equivalent to high stock chart from high charts and its for free !! Comes under MIT license.Check the below URL for more info.
http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index

Answer (score 0):

I like high stock chart to plot stock market data but its not free for commercial purposes.

Humble finance is nice and free but I was not able to get out put if the number of data point were less then 35 on humble finance.

jfreechart and jqplot can also be used to plot OHCL data.